# Fetching Facebook likes by date in JSON format?

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-like, fetch

How can I get likes of some page on Facebook, in JSON format?
Is this possible to get the likes over time? Like an array of likes per date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're an admin of a Facebook Page, you can use the Insights functionality to request details about the Page likes

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/insights/ You can use it like

```
GET /{page_id}/insights/page_fan_adds
GET /{page_id}/insights/page_fan_removes
```

etc. Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/insights/ for an overview of available metrics.

If you aren't the own of a Page, you can only request the Page information on a daily basis and build the database for yourself:

```
GET /{page_id}?fields=id,likes
```